# Cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' in google colab

Tags: python, pycaret

I'm trying to install pycaret==3.0.0 in google colab, But I'm having a problem, the library requires Jinja2 to be installed which I did, but then It finally throws off another error.

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-26-4f8843d24b3a> in <module>()
----> 1 import jinja2
      2 from pycaret.regression import *

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2/filters.py in <module>()
     11 from markupsafe import escape
     12 from markupsafe import Markup
---> 13 from markupsafe import soft_unicode
     14 
     15 from ._compat import abc

ImportError: cannot import name 'soft_unicode' from 'markupsafe' (/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/markupsafe/__init__.py)
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is caused by [upgrade](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/3661) in MarkupSafe:2.1.0 where they have removed soft_unicode, try using:

```
pip install markupsafe==2.0.1
```

Comment: currently not working

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this. This will install the latest release of pycaret and should take care of all dependencies for you. Just remember to restart the kernel after installation for the install to take effect correctly.

```
pip install -U --pre pycaret
```

Comment: Hi could you answer this if you happen to know https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73362136/unboundlocalerror-local-variable-fix-imbalance-model-name-referenced-before-a

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve the same issue:

```
pip install -U markupsafe
```

so that I can use the latest version. I also had to update jinja2 with the same type of command.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause with your question may stem from a dependency management conflict between two software ecosystems. According to the error message, your markupsafe was installed using pip at the path `/root/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/markupsafe/`. The jinja2 that depends on it was installed using apt at the path `/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/jinja2`. The versions of the two are not compatible. In fact, there is a version of markupsafe in the system that jinja2 correctly depends on, but the Python interpreter prioritizes the markupsafe installed by pip, leading to this issue. There are typically two solutions to this problem: (1) Use pip to uninstall markupsafe, and then reinstall it using apt, or uninstall jinja2 using apt and reinstall it using pip. (2) Use Python's imp module to customize the path and import the markupsafe from the apt path before importing jinja2. An example is as follows:

```
import imp
path = ['/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages']
fp, pathname, description = imp.find_module('markupsafe', path)
imp.load_module("markupsafe", fp, pathname, description)
```

Hope my diagnosis is helpful to you！

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```bash
pip install markupsafe==2.1.1
conda update jupyter
```