# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fix_imbalance_model_name' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-3.x, pycaret

Getting this error while initializing
**fix_imbalance=True,fix_imbalance_method=smote** Pycaret Classification Setup.

```
1735             else []
   1736         )
-> 1737         + (
   1738             [
   1739                 ["Transform Target", transform_target_param],

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'fix_imbalance_model_name' referenced before assignment
```

I have initialised `smote = SMOTETomek(random_state=2022)` before runing setup.
Is this a bug?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to answer this question in the current form due to missing information. Please provide a complete reproducible example along with metadata such as package versions, etc. For detailed guidance on what information is needed, please refer to the GitHub Issues (type Bug if you suspect this to be one)

https://github.com/pycaret/pycaret/issues/new?assignees=&labels=bug&template=bug_report.yml&title=%5BBUG%5D%3A+

Comment: This error occurs when installing Pycaret full, and we run a classification model where we set ` fix_imbalance=True,fix_imbalance_method=smote`

Comment: Please file a bug report in the GitHub repo with all the required details.